# How to Create Hamming Window in Audio Signal Processing

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, fft, windowing

Please help me, I'am newbie...

I have an audio -- fs=16000 (.wav).  I want to touch this audio with hamming window.

this is my code:

```
y = audioread('Mono.wav');

sr = 16000; %sampling rate

w = 512; %window size

T = w/sr; %period

% t is an array of times at which the hamming function is evaluated

t = linspace(0, 1, 16000);

twindow = t(1:512);


hamming = 0.54 - 0.46 * cos((2 * pi * twindow)/T);

plot(hamming);

title('Hamming');
```

**Quetion:**

1) how to make overlapping frames and stores these  frames into a matrix?

(Create Frames)

2) overlap adds the frames from the input matrix

(Fusion Frames)

Thankyou for your attention

Comment: You should use the in-built hamming function in Matlab rather than writing it yourself. Type `help hamming` and you will see a description of how to use it. In the reference page you will probably find examples of what you are trying to achieve as well.

Comment: Hello Matia My old friend. I've come to talk with you again (...) :D

Answer (score 1):

To make overlap frame, I suggest you the `buffer` function:

```
>> x = 1:100;
>> y = buffer(x, 20, 5) % create a frame of 20 elements with 5 elements overlap.

y =

     0    11    26    41    56    71    86
     0    12    27    42    57    72    87
     0    13    28    43    58    73    88
     0    14    29    44    59    74    89
     0    15    30    45    60    75    90
     1    16    31    46    61    76    91
     2    17    32    47    62    77    92
     [...]
     9    24    39    54    69    84    99
    10    25    40    55    70    85   100
    11    26    41    56    71    86     0
    12    27    42    57    72    87     0
    13    28    43    58    73    88     0
    14    29    44    59    74    89     0
    15    30    45    60    75    90     0
```

To apply a hamming window to each frame, just use `y .* hamming(20)`.